# Array of pointers and Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, scanf

I am trying to write a program in C that reads from an input file ("input0") which follows the format:
John Doe 1230 4.0

I am trying to read from the document using fscanf and enter those values into a struct. Currently, though, after compiling and once I run my code, I run into the enigmatic "Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)."

The line in my code currently giving off this error the line with fscanf statement. I can't find the solution to this.

Additionally, strcpy gives an error once its uncommented. I get a warning when I run the code, which I believe has to be with a discrepancy with what is a pointer and what's the string, another problem I can't fix. Any help would be appreciated.

```
typedef struct {
    char fname[1000];
    char lname[1000];
    long int id;
    double gpa;
} student_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *db;
    student_t students[1000];
    char* fname[1000];
    char* lname[1000];
    long int id[1000];
    double gpa[1000];
    long int i, j;
    i = 0;
    db = fopen("input0", "r");
    while(fscanf(db, "%s %s %d %lf", fname[i], lname[i], id[i], gpa[i]) != EOF) {
        //strcpy(students[i].fname, fname[i]);
        //strcpy(students[i].lname, lname[i]);
        students[i].id = id[i];
        students[i].gpa = gpa[i];
        i++;
    }
    for(j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    //printf("%s %s %d %f\n", _SJ.fname, _SJ.lname, _SJ.id, _ST.gpa);
    }
    fclose(db);
}
```

Comment: the way you read from file is very fragile, instead use fgets/sscanf alt. fgets/strtok.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare e.g.

```
char* fname[1000];
```

you have an array of `1000` *uninitialized pointers*. Trying to use one of those pointers will lead to *undefined behavior*. You need to either allocate memory for the pointers, or point them to some other (already allocated) memory.

Actually, I think what you really meant to do is

```
fscanf(db, "%s %s %d %lf",
    students[i].fname, students[i].lname, &students[i].id, &students[i].gpa)
```

---

I also suggest you read e.g. [this `fscanf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), as `fscanf` can return other values that means there are errors in the input (for example if the input file is malformed).

Comment: Adding `fscanf(db, "%999s %999s %d %lf", ... ` would protect the code fromw overflowing `.fname` and `.lname`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
while(fscanf(db, "%s %s %d %lf", fname[i], lname[i], id[i], gpa[i]) != EOF)
```

to

```
while(fscanf(db, "%s %s %d %lf", students[i].fname, students[i].lname, &students[i].id, &students[i].gpa) != EOF)
```

Then probably you do not need any `strcpy` or copy back `int` and `double` to the stucture.

`char *fname[1000]` will allocate 1000 pointers of `char`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use `&` for `long int` and `double` in `fscanf`

```
while(fscanf(db, "%s %s %d %lf", fname[i], lname[i], &id[i], &gpa[i]) != EOF)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed some problems:

```
typedef struct {
    char fname[1000];
    char lname[1000];
    long int id;
    double gpa;
} student_t;

student_t students[1000];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *db;   
    long int i=0, j;    
    db = fopen("input0.txt", "r");
    if (db == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening file input0");
        return -1;
    }
    while (fscanf(db, "%s %s %d %lf", students[i].fname, students[i].lname, 
                                      &students[i].id, &students[i].gpa) != EOF) 
    {       
        i++;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        printf("%s %s %d %f\n", students[j].fname, students[j].lname, students[j].id, students[j].gpa);
    }
    fclose(db);
}
```

You can read directly to the students array, avoiding having to play with strcpy. The missing & were added too.
Please note that I moved students[1000] outside the main function, as with the standard stack size of VS2013 the code generated a stack overflow. When opening file, always check if you managed to open them... this will save many hours of debug pain in the future. The j<=i condition was changed to j

In your original code:

```
char* fname[1000];
```

You used 1000 char*, but this line only allocates the space for the pointers itself. I think you were trying to write something like:

```
char fname[1000];
```

In this case, frame would have 1000 chars you could use to store the name read from the input file. It is very important to note the diference between these two lines before going further studying C. In the case of fname[1000], you could read to fname, i.e., no indexes. Then strcpy(students[i].fname, fname). I hope it helps.